# Can I publish a picture from a third-party site in my article, mentioning the source?

Tags: copyright, legal

I'm writing an article about Blockchain to publish in my LinkedIn and the blog of the company that I work for, and I mighty use some third-party pictures. Some of them I found on the internet, from websites such as Financial Times. However, I'm not sure if I can use third-party pictures on my publication because of copyright, even if I mention the source.

Could someone clarify if is allowed or not?

Answer (score 3):

It's only allowed if you ask them first and receive written (probably email) permission before using the image(s). In this case the credit would read something like "Reproduced with permission from..."

The exception to this is if a website has a blanket rule saying that images can be reproduced for editorial purposes. Getty Images, for instance has this policy. Again, you have to give them proper credit.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt respond and clarifying it. Does this apply for self-publishing via Linkedin Pulse, or just for publishing as a business?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference if you are making money from the site or if you are just publishing it for personal interest. Copyright still applies.

Comment: Ok. In this case, I'll design my own pictures to avoid copyright problems.

Comment: This led me to another doubt. If it is not possible to publish third-party content for personal interest, it may not be allowed to share third-party posts via Facebook, as it contains third-party content and would infringe copywriting. However, everyone share posts on Facebook. Why is that?

Comment: That's really a separate question. Sharing a link to something is very different to extracting an image and incorporating into your own publication. When you share a link you don't COPY anything, you're just pointing at it.